# Use HTML entities in django template

Tags: python, html, django, html-entities

I want to use HTML entities in my Django template. I know that I can do something like this

```
<th>0&ge;a&lt;10</th>
```

and it will work correctly. But I send to my template list with that which looks like

```
list_of_ranges = ['Name', 'Type', 'a<1', '5<a<10' .......]
```

So in a template in for loop, I want to use `&ge, &lt`, and others for values that contain '>', '>=' and others.

I tried to use it in the list before sending it to the template, but it's not working correctly. See below.

```
list_of_ranges = ['Name', 'Type', 'a&lt;<1' .......]
```

and in template fo like this `{{list_of_ranges.2}}`

Result: `a&lt;<1`

Could you help, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) built-in template tag:

```
list_of_ranges = ['Name', 'Type', 'a<1', '5<a<10' .......]
```

```
{{ list_of_ranges.2|safe }}
```

**NOTE** that `safe` marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output. This is a bit risky.